# Finding the solutions for $\sin x = \sqrt x - 5$

Tags: systems-of-equations, periodic-functions

Is there a way to retrieve the points where a function like $f(x) = \sqrt x - 5$ intersects with a periodic function like $\sin x$?

With a constant $f(x) = c$, it's easy: when it intersects, there are infinite solutions, by using $\arcsin x$ we can get the angle which produced $c$, and every other solution is a the same interval ($2k\pi$) away from the last.

For some reason, I think the derivative $df(x)/dx$ might be significant.

**Edit:** To clarify, this can be done using numerical methods or by iterating on points over some range of $x$ and computing their values. However, I'm interested in finding an analytical solution, if it can be done!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you familiar with a use of numerical analysis to compute roots of equations?

Comment: While not a hard rule, the fact that [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinx%3Dsqrt%28x%29+-+5) can only give approximations means that, more than likely, the best you can do yourself is approximate, i.e. there are likely no closed-form solutions.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Small nitpick: $f(x) = c$ **may** have infinitely many solutions. It also may have none at all, depending on $c$ and $f$.

Comment: Look up *Newton's Method*.

Comment: Sorry, there is no closed form solution. Only numerical methods apply.